# Get models as variable from URL to Views django

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, models

I make Api for my database by django REST framework , i get model nickname from `url.py` as a variable `var` then use it in `views.py` to determine 
which models will use with any function i want.

So i make dictionary collection of models `value`, use `var` as a key and put result model in `data` variable to use model as i need .

**The problem :**

when i make initial value to `data` it not change in function call, or i don't what's happen but when i use invalid nickname it return error also i can't make `data` as `None` value , i try a lot of things like `getattr` but all is failed ,  i think it can solved by OOP python but my knowledge about it doesn't help me .

**Not :** i use django 2.0, database mysql, python 3.6

**Edit :** if i want similar method but on `pk` to use it in data_detail, i try this line `data.objects.get(pk=pk)` but it doesn't work

url.py

```
from .views import data_detail, data_name

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<var>[\w-]+)/$', data_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<var>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', data_detail, name='id')
]
```

views.py

```
from .models import Authors, Users, Categories

value = {'user': Users,
         'author': Authors,
         'cate': Categories,
        }

data = value['user']

def data_list(request, var):
     global data
     data = value[var]
     return DataList.as_view()(request)

class DataList(ListAPIView):                         
     queryset = data.objects.all()
     AllDataSerializer.Meta.model = data
     serializer_class = AllDataSerializer

def data_detail(request, var, pk):
     global data
     data = value[var]
     data = data.objects.get(pk=pk)
     return DataDetail.as_view()(request)

class DataDetail(ListAPIView):                         
     queryset = data.objects.all()
     AllDataSerializer.Meta.model = data
     serializer_class = AllDataSerializer
```

Comment: Never use `global` in a web application. It's also not a bad idea to avoid it generally.

Comment: thanks for advice , i will remember it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from .models import Authors, Users, Categories

value = {'user': Users,
         'author': Authors,
         'cate': Categories,
        }


def data_list(request, var):
     data = value[var]
     return DataList.as_view(**{'model_name':data})(request)

class DataList(ListAPIView): 
     model_name = None

     def get_queryset(self):
         return self.model_name.objects.all()

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         AllDataSerializer.Meta.model = self.model_name
         return AllDataSerializer
```

Comment: But in as_view we are sending model name through kwargs and it should be work

Comment: It think. you should check with self.kwargs.get('model_name') in DataList view

Comment: it return `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'`

Comment: thank you very much ,, i work 
but you forget in your code to `return`model in `get_queryset`